# Como transformar gráfico de dispersão de pontos em densidade?

Tags: r, gráfico, plot, gráfico-de-dispersão

Gostaria de saber como transformar um gráfico de dispersão de pontos em um gráfico de densidade de pontos na região, por exemplo, onde existem poucos pontos a cor da região será clara, onde existem muitos pontos a cor da região será mais escura. 
Grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando o `ggplot2` o seguinte gráfico de dispersão:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlim(0.5, 6) +
  ylim(40, 110)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ficar assim, apenas trocando a linha `geom_point`:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon") +
  xlim(0.5, 6) +
  ylim(40, 110)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também pode fazê-lo assim:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) +
  geom_bin2d() + 
  xlim(0.5, 6) +
  ylim(40, 110)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]